# MFi EADemo sample code send test string to the accessory

Tags: ios, xcode, external, external-accessory, mfi

I am using  sample code for EADemo. Its working fine and show MFI device list. but when I tried to sending right test string to the accessory. Its getting response.

**Code for sending test string:**

```
- (IBAction)sendStringButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{
    if ([_stringToSendText isFirstResponder]) {
        [_stringToSendText resignFirstResponder];
    }

    const char *buf = [[_stringToSendText text] UTF8String];
    if (buf)
    {
        uint32_t len = (uint32_t)strlen(buf) + 1;
        [[EADSessionController sharedController] writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:len]];
    }
}
```

**And getting response code:**
UIViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // watch for the accessory being disconnected
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_accessoryDidDisconnect:) name:EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
    // watch for received data from the accessory
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(_sessionDataReceived:) name:EADSessionDataReceivedNotification object:nil];

    EADSessionController *sessionController = [EADSessionController sharedController];

    _accessory = [sessionController accessory];
    [self setTitle:[sessionController protocolString]];
    [sessionController openSession];
    _totalBytesRead = 0;
}
```

**Received response in :**

```
// Data was received from the accessory, real apps should do something with this data but currently:
//    1. bytes counter is incremented
//    2. bytes are read from the session controller and thrown away

    - (void)_sessionDataReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        EADSessionController *sessionController = (EADSessionController *)[notification object];
        uint32_t bytesAvailable = 0;

        while ((bytesAvailable = (uint32_t)[sessionController readBytesAvailable]) > 0) {
            NSData *data = [sessionController readData:bytesAvailable];
            if (data) {

                _totalBytesRead = _totalBytesRead + bytesAvailable;
            }
        }

        [_receivedBytesCountLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bytes Received from Session: %u", (unsigned int)_totalBytesRead]];
    }
```

But my problem is when I have send to wrong test string to the accessory.
I am not getting any response for failed.

I need to receive failed response.